# How to parse and get headers property values externally in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I need to parse and get headers property value which I send via `MessagingGateway`, I doubt if it has something to do with `IntegrationEvaluationContext`

Here is what I tried and failed miserably:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow deleteFiles(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from("integration.channel.bulk-delete")
            .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(),
            AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.LS,"headers[path]")
                    .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.NAME_ONLY)
                    .filterFunction(file->{
                     //Here I'm trying to get the age value from headers
                        int age = ExpressionUtils.intExpression("headers[age]").getValue(integrationEvaluationContext.getObject(),Integer.class);
                        Instant decidedTime = Instant.now().minus(age, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
                        return Instant.ofEpochSecond(file.getAttrs().getMTime()).isBefore(decidedTime);
                    }))
                   .get();
```

The error message:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on null
```

I even tried autowiring `StandardEvaluationContext` and passing:

```
new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("headers[age]").getValue(standardEvaluationContext)
```

How can I get the EvaluationContext and pass it so that `headers[]` get parsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filters don't have access to the gateway's input message; they only have access to the `LsEntry`.

You need to provide the `age` some other way, perhaps store it in a `ThreadLocal`.

```java
public class AgeHolder {

     private static final ages = new ThreadLocal<Integer>;

     public static setAge(int age) {
         ages.set(age);
     }

     public static Integer getAge() {
         Integer age = ages.get();
         ages.remove();
         return age;
     }

}
```

Then `T(AgeHolder).getAge()` in the expression.

Or you can do the filtering in Spring Integration instead

```java
    .from(Sfp...) // not NAME_ONLY
    .split
    .filter(...) // use the `headers` and `payload`
    .transform(...) -> LsEntry -> name
    .aggregate()
    ...
```

Comment: I just need `List<String>` file names so I have `NAME_ONLY` Option. I already have access to `mTime` from the `filterFunction's` consumer method this is working fine,  the actual problem is I have a `headers[age]` that I passed through gateway How can I parse and get value of `headers[age]` and store it in a variable, you can refer my `filterFunction()` method

Comment: Sorry, I misread the configuration, I assumed you were  using SI filters. See my edit.

Comment: A `ThreadLocal` is the best way to go over here. You set the value before `Sftp.outboundGateway()`, use it in the filter function and remove just after the use.

Comment: A Big Thanks, My bad I was doing the wrong way, trying to access headers in `filterFunction()` method, I'll just change the whole flow to the Spring Integration way as suggested by you

Comment: Since you are using a gateway, you'll have to add an aggregator after the transformer to collect the names back into a `List<String>`.